# Do I have to know compiler theory if I want to work in AI and machine learning

Tags: compiler-construction, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, theory

I am interested in the field of AI and machine learning and I am fairly good at mathematics and statistics and programming in general. However I lack a formal CS education and my undergraduate degree was in an unrelated field.

What traditional undergraduate courses that I missed are important to take in order to be able to proceed to a Master's in AI? The elephant of the room is compiler theory which I have zero knowledge about.

Comment: This is something you should ask the professors at the university you're attending.

Comment: I find that a lot of people working in this field don't have computer science degrees.  (All mine are in mechanical engineering.)  Compiler theory is good for writing compilers, but that's not what machine learning is about.

Comment: I am not attending any university right now. I thought I might ask this in a related Q&A website.

Comment: In the universe of [Stack Exchange Q&A sites](http://stackexchange.com/sites) much better candidates for finding an answer to your question (probably without asking) would be the "Programmers", "Computer Science", "Theoretical Computer Science" and above all the "Data Science" - "_Q&A for Machine Learning specialists_"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finished a postgraduate degree in AI without the need of Compiler Theory.

From an academic perspective, I believe that the subjects that helped prepare me for AI were, as you stated, Statistical Methods, Mathematics and Programming (I believe Object-Oriented and Data Structures helped most for this area).  In addition to these, Research Methods was very useful for reading what models are out there and learning how to apply these models to your own problems.

There have been some really good comments that have already been posted on this question.  As Neil has stated, if you are looking to specialise in a particular area, there will be a need for particular skills above others.  Also, Juhana has raised a good point that the university would be a good source of information on this topic as they no doubt will have determined the prerequisites for the AI subjects.

I hope this can help you into the wonderful world of machine learning!

Answer (score 1):

No, 'academics and theory' and 'real world development' can function without each other. Although, the exposure never hurts, right?

How about narrowing your focus on Math/Logic (example: I use [relational algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra) every day) and attend courses critical to machine learning by visiting [OpenCourseWare and searching for artificial intelligence](http://search.mit.edu/search?q=Artificial%20intelligence&spell=1&site=ocw&client=mit&getfields=*&output=xml_no_dtd&requiredfields=WT%252Ecg_s:Course%20Home%7CWT%252Ecg_s:Resource%20Home&sectionlimit=WT%252Ecg_s:Course%20Home%7CWT%252Ecg_s:Resource%20Home&ie=UTF-8&access=p&proxystylesheet=http://ocw.mit.edu/search/google-ocw.xsl)...Its free! Supplement the rest with your University courses.

Your true learning will be your real life decisions and daily code application.

Expediting your graduation never hurts either.

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting into text mining/information extraction/NLP, then you probably want to understand lexing and parsing, which is part of compiling.

Lucene/Solr for example have custom query parsers.

Answer (score 1):

I have worked on compilers, AI and in a university without a degree. I was thinking about getting one but the head of department advised me not to, saying that I could never come up with the ideas I did if I had a degree.

The only real crossover between AI and compiler theory is that of processing natural language. Compiler concepts such as parsing, syntax and lexical tokens are required but learning them in such a simplified environment does little to prepare you.

So long as you are familiar with things being composed of other things, you are well on your way. Look up sentence structure, break it down first by character tokens (Bob's ball, walking etc) and then parts of speech (noun clause, verb clause) and then lexical concepts (an object called a ball, a state of ownership, an action of throw, a tense (time) of past).

Familiarize yourself with the concepts but don't waste too much time on formal compiler theory. The interesting stuff comes when processing the results of your parsing!

Answer (score 0):

Theory of Computation is probably a good fundamental course to take.
In that course, you will learn things like if a particular problem has a solution or not, the complexity of a particular problem (NP-Hard, NP-Complete, etc.), Turing machine (which is the basis of all modern computers), languages and grammars, finite automata (state machines), etc.

Here are a few good wiki articles pertaining to computational theory:

- [Computational Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_theory)
- [Complexities of problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-complete)